# Minimization of $L_1$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I need to solve the minimization problem:
$$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} |x_i| \rightarrow \min$$
$$Ax \leq b$$

I want to solve it by linear programming. My idea was to make a substitution $|x_i| \leq t_i$. And then solve LP problem
$$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} t_i \rightarrow \min$$
$$Ax \leq b$$

However, I don't know how to back to $x_i$ variables. How can I do this?

P.S. Maybe there is an another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the two constraints
$$\begin{align}
x_i &\leq t_i \\
-x_i &\leq t_i
\end{align}$$
for every $1\leq i\leq n$. For any optimal solution to the minimization problem, you must then have $t_i = \lvert x_i\rvert$.

Comment: For example, if I have solution t = (1, 1, 1) for some problem, it means that solution for x's is a cube with faces from -1 to 1, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you have that $t$ any $|x_i|\leq 1$ is feasible. However, that direction is not interesting. The interesting direction is that at optimality $t_i$ will be equal to $|x_i|$. Your optimization problem is in both $x$ and $t$, so you never have to recover $x$ from $t$ or anything like that, as your question hints at

Comment: Indeed: after the LP is run and a minimizer is found, you have $x$: the $x_i$ are still among the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to repleace $x_i$ by $x_i^+-x_i^-$. Then  $|x_i|=x_i^++x_i^-$. And the model becomes

$$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i^++x_i^-) \rightarrow \min$$
$$A(x^+-x^-) \leq b$$

$$x_i^+,x_i^-\geq 0$$

This model can be solved with the well known Two-phase simplex method.